# What is the final state of a PostgreSQL dump if there are inserts/updates/deletes during the backup process?

Tags: postgresql

What happens if I'm making insert/update/delete operations on a PostgreSQL database (on all tables at the same time) while it's being backup-ed with `pg_dump`? Is the dump consistent? What will be the content of the dump?

If some sort of locking mechanism is being placed during the backup, will that prevent me from doing insert/update/delete operations?

Or maybe the backup process will ignore the results of all operations launched after the backup process was started? If so, how does that work exactly? Where are the results of all operations saved?

Answer (score 1):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

> It makes consistent backups even if the database is being used concurrently

The dump will contain the state of the database as it was at the moment the dump was started. For details on how this is achieved, see the introduction to [Concurrency Control](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html)